# Using PyMongo in a Jupyter Lab notebook won't close any connection to the MongoDB server

Tags: python, linux, mongodb, jupyter-notebook

So, I'm using a **Jupyter Lab** notebook to connect to our production database. After a few days of work, we noticed how the server displays hundreds upon hundreds of active conenctions to the database, listed as established (running "*netstat -na*").

This is terribly bad, and we identified the issues as coming from the python kernel opening connections to the server without actually ever closing them, even if expelicitely told to do so.

This a redacted version of the code we are using to connect to the server, ran in a notebook cell by itself, separated from the other code. We isolated the issue and we are certain it comes from these lines of code:

```py
client = MongoClient(url, maxIdleTimeMS=120000)
db = client["database"]
coll = db["data"]

query = # Our query
data = list(coll.find(query))

client.close()
```

Why is this happening? What are we doing wrong? Why doesn't the .close() method actually close the connection?

Comment: Why are you trying to close the connection? Most applications should really leave the connection open for their lifecycle. Connection time is expensive, so we really don't want to do that more than once where possible.

Comment: I didn't close it before, haveing read about it, but those connections are piling up at quite a considerable speed. How do you prevent that from happening? The server would probably crash for this reason, sooner or later

Comment: You need to give more context. It would seem that you are likely calling the code here "per request", and that is what is essentially wrong. Instead of doing that there needs to be a way the connection can be made once, and then whatever code is calling methods on the collection need to get that connection instance instead.

Comment: This operation is only called once, at the start of the script. Only the variable **data** is used, after this code is executed

Comment: Show the code around it please. We need to understand where this is actually being called. You "think" it's called once, but your statement about connections on the server end tell us that something different is happening to what you "think".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been using MongoDB for quite a while now in our production environment and have faced such problems in the past. 
`data = list(coll.find(query))` this line of code actually materializes the results of the query that your cursor returns and causes the connection to stay alive. The result of a query is a generator and should be consumed as is in a loop. Materializing the Cursor into a `list()` causes all the data to be pulled into the memory causing it to crash at times, as opposed to the cursor which points to the first entry in the result-set.

You can simply perform the following operation on the cursor:

`for elem in cursor: 
    do_something`

and not require the call to the `close()` method

Secondly, with Jupyter Notebooks, you need to stop the session after you are done with your work. Unless this is done, the notebook shall always keep the connection to MongoDB alive eating up resources along the way.

Comment: What if I want all the data as a list, without keeping the connection alive? Should I just do something like *data = [elem for elem in cursor]*?

Comment: You can perform the list comprehension but it is not advisable to do so in production environments in case the result-set does not fit into the available memory, it causes the MongoDB to crash and we don't want that. Plus, the Jupyter Notebook needs to be closed once your tests are done as it keeps the connection alive. In a script you can call the `close()` method and it works as per the documentation but the behavior differs with Jupyter or Zeppelin Notebooks